# Cannot set property 'grid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, ng-grid

I'm new to angular and ng-grid, I am calling a simple static json file but the grid is not showing at all, the message I'm getting is:

> Cannot set property 'grid' of undefined

Can anyone help?

My code looks like this

```
angular.module('healthyLivingApp')
  .controller('SubscribersCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:9000/subscribers.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.subscribers = data;
    });
     $scope.gridOptions = {
        data:'subscribers'
    }

  });

app.js

.module('healthyLivingApp', [
'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngGrid',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])

HTML

<h1>Subscribers</h1>
<div class="gridStyles" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
```

I'm using bower, Angular  "1.3.12", ng-grid " "2.0.14"", jQuery " 2.1.3"

Comment: This works for me, what order are your angular/nggrid and jquery scripts loaded in your html?  Also, what exactly does subscribers.json return?  See: http://plnkr.co/edit/ersNjlKz4xjlmoIGgUli?p=preview

Comment: returns  a simple object like this   [
{"no":"1","name":"Betty", "loyalty": 3,"joinDate":"3/5/10", "userType":"Free"},
{"no":"2","name":"John", "loyalty": 5,"joinDate":"3/5/05", "userType":"Premium"},
{"no":"3","name":"Peter", "loyalty": 6,"joinDate":"3/5/10", "userType":"Free"}
]

Comment: It is showing the data but not the grid

Comment: the css file was missing, thanks a lot for that plunker, however the console still showing me that error, i have no idea what it is

Answer (score 0):

There is an async task in your controller

```
$http.get('http://localhost:9000/subscribers.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.subscribers = data;
});
```

When your controller finishes initialization and Angular starts to render DOM, this async hasn't finished, which means `$scope.subscribers` is still undefined. You already claim `ng-grid` should read data from `subscribers`

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data:'subscribers'
}
```

So, a proper solution is, define `$scope.subscribers` at the top of your controller

```
angular.module('healthyLivingApp')
  .controller('SubscribersCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
      $scope.subscribers = [];
      $http.get('http://localhost:9000/subscribers.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.subscribers = data;
      });
      $scope.gridOptions = {
        data:'subscribers'
      };
  });
```

Comment: The css file was missing ```ng-grid.min.css``` the grind is howing obviously now, when you have an app running with yo, sometimes there is to much going on, I miss that (sorry about that) however the conosle still showing the same error even if I try your solution, don't have a clue what is trying to say

Comment: @rolando Your problem is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082380/ng-grid-cannot-set-property-griddim-of-undefined), so you can take a look at it. I suppose my solution can solve your problem because I can create a ng-grid sample successfully.

Comment: I read that before asking the question, apparently his issue was that he define the gridOptions scope inside the succes call which i didn't, if you look at this plunk done by @Nicholas Smith 12 http://plnkr.co/edit/ersNjlKz4xjlmoIGgUli?p=preview, the grid shows even if you take out the $scope.subscribers = [];  but for some reason i sitll get the Cannot set property 'grid' of undefined on my app

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about the data binding policy.

In the view, if you bind some data, it will bind with reference. In you code, the view will bind with `subscribers` in the $scope. But you update the reference in your controller then the data is got.

So, try to bind with `someObjName.subscribers`. Then the `someObjName` will be bind and watched. If the attribute of the object is changed, the view will be updated.